# Scrapy - Parse_item not being called

Tags: html-parsing, scrapy

I'm having two main problems

1) The parse_item method is not being called/executed after crawling a page
2) When the "callback='self.parse_item'" is included in the rules, scrapy does not continue to follow the links. Instead, it only follows the links immediately available from the Start Urls.

Here is the code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from sheprime.items import SheprimeItem

class HerroomSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "herroom"
    allowed_domains = ["herroom.com"]
    start_urls = [
                  "http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p314-trocadero-sheer-seamless-racerback-bra.shtml",
 "http://www.herroom.com/hosiery.aspx",


rules = [
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.shtml', )), callback='self.parse_item')


   ]

def parse_item(self, response):
    print "some message"  

#I have put in this simple parse function, because I just want to get it to work
```

Thanks for your help,

L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.shtml', )), callback='self.parse_item')
```

It should be:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.shtml', )), callback='parse_item')
```

This works for me:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class HerroomSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "herroom"
    allowed_domains = ["herroom.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p314-trocadero-sheer-seamless-racerback-bra.shtml",
        "http://www.herroom.com/hosiery.aspx"
    ]


    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.shtml', )), callback='parse_item')
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print "some message"
```

Results:

```
vic@wic:~/projects/test$ scrapy crawl herroom
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.15.1 started (bot: domains_scraper)
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, CloseSpider, CoreStats, SpiderState
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: Pipeline
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [herroom] INFO: Spider opened
2012-07-09 08:08:51+0400 [herroom] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-07-09 08:08:52+0400 [herroom] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p314-trocadero-sheer-seamless-racerback-bra.shtml> (referer: None)
2012-07-09 08:08:54+0400 [herroom] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.herroom.com/hosiery.aspx> (referer: None)
2012-07-09 08:08:55+0400 [herroom] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele.shtml> (referer: http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p314-trocadero-sheer-seamless-racerback-bra.shtml)
some message
2012-07-09 08:08:56+0400 [herroom] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p300-trocadero-strapless-bra.shtml> (referer: http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p314-trocadero-sheer-seamless-racerback-bra.shtml)
some message
2012-07-09 08:08:57+0400 [herroom] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p342-trocadero-push-up-bra-with-racerback.shtml> (referer: http://www.herroom.com/simone-perele-12p314-trocadero-sheer-seamless-racerback-bra.shtml)
some message
```

Comment: I tried both of those options but could not get either of them to return any the print message. Did it work for you? Maybe there is another problem on my side that I'm missing.

Comment: @RunwithLuke, see my answer update. the second version i suggested doesn't work, as `self` is not available in the class body, but the first option should work you as it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. after hours of muddling with it, it ended up being an indent problem! Thanks again for your help